# Why am I not getting any output from my code?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, loops, while-loop

Here's a text-based Python implementation for an algorithm to calculate if a number is prime using a *REPEAT...UNTIL* loop.
whenever I try to run this it doesn't output anything.
Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with this code?
FYI I'm a beginner. Thank you in advance!

```
prime = True

number = int(input("Enter a number :  "))
counter  = 2

while True:
 
   modulus = number % counter
   if modulus == 0:
          prime == False
   counter = counter + 1
          
   #The loop for until statement
   if counter == number-1 or prime == False:
          break
          
if prime == True:
   print("Prime :  ", number)
else:
   print("Not prime :  ", number)
```

Comment: It does print an output, but I think you need to reconsider the algorithm. As is, it would consider 4 as a prime. Something-something about your second ```if statement```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't output anything, but the line `prime == False` is wrong, it should be

```
prime = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prime = True

number = int(input("Enter a number :  "))
 counter  = 2

 while True:
 
     modulus = number % counter
     if modulus == 0:
        prime == False
    counter = counter + 1
          
    #The loop for until statement
    if counter == number-1 or prime == False:
        break
          
if prime == True:
    print("Prime :  ", number)
else:
    print("Not prime :  ", number)`
```

As you can see in line number 10 prime = False not prime ==  False

Answer (score 0):

Give this version a shot.

Main issues were:

1. The `prime == False` statement under the first `if` loop is set up as a boolean expression, not a variable assignment.
2. Set the `while` loop to run `while prime == True`. In this way, the loop will break the moment it detects the first case of contradiction between the input number and the prime designation

```
prime = True

number = int(input("Enter a number :  "))
counter  = 2

while prime == True:
   modulus = number % counter
   if modulus == 0:
       prime = False
   counter = counter + 1
   if counter == number-1 or prime == False:
       break       
if prime == True:
   print("Prime :  ", number)
else:
   print("Not prime :  ", number)
```